# Interpretation of OR

Tags: meaning, biology

Consider the sentence,
"ribosomes are attached to the outside of the endoplasmic reticulum or nuclear envelope."

Interpretation A - "ribosomes are attached to the OUTSIDE of the endoplasmic reticulum or to the OUTSIDE of nuclear envelope".

Interpretation B - "ribosomes are attached to the OUTSIDE of the endoplasmic reticulum, or attached to(not specifically to the OUTSIDE of) the nuclear envelope".

which one is correct?

Comment: Actually, not knowing the subject at all, I would read that sentence as if _nuclear envelope_ was just a synonym for _endoplasmic reticulum_. Google suggests that this is not the case. I find the sentence confusing, and I would assume that it was supposed to be clear for someone well-versed in the subject matter.

Comment: @oerkelens I agree with you, it is written as if the ER and the NE were synonyms. Forgetting the word "outside" for the moment, I would go so far as to say that grammatically (or at the least idiomatically) it does say that.  For if they are different things, and the ribosomes could be attached to either one (the only alternative possibility) it should read "The ribosomes are attached to...the ER *or to the* NE*.

Comment: As the sentence itself is ambiguous, A, B or @oerkelens' C (an appositive construction) is required, and the original is unacceptable.

Comment: i can agree with @Edwin Ashworth's comment. what i came as my conclusion is that the sentence itself is ambiguous so i should seek help from someone who specializes in the subject matter itself. Am i right?

Comment: I found help. I asked this in biology.stackexchange.com, https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/68163/ribosomes-location, in case somebody else have the same problem on interpretation of science sentences like this.

Comment: This question was posted on SE Biology, and I answered it in a comment because it was not about biology. I explained that it was linguistically ambiguous and that in theory the third alternative mentioned by @oerkelens was possible, although biologists would know that was not what was meant. My comment here is to reassert my opinion that it is linguistically ambiguous. It is a poor sentence because I was not aware that ribosomes were associated with the nuclear envelope so the meaning isn't even obvious. However it is hardly a question of general interest for SE EL&U.

Comment: @oerkelens, WS2 Wouldn’t there need to be a comma before the “or” for that interpretation to be valid?

Comment: @Scott A comma would strengthen that interpretation for sure, but even without it, it seems to work. If one were to follow the strict rules of commas, the absence of the comma _might_ invalidate the interpretation, but the fact that the interpretation _happened_ the way it did without the comma shows that comma-rules are far from absolute, and that the author should have considered constructing a less convoluted sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi it's me again from 6 years later. Today I've been studying Natural Language Processing (NLP) subject for my Degree. I came across an interesting topic called "Semantic Ambiguity" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_ambiguity) which is one of the reasons for making NLP a pretty difficult area.

So my answer to my past-self on this is, well the usage of OR indeed is ambiguous here and it really depends on the context. As for this particular sentence, `Interpretation A` is the correct one (confirmed from a biology standpoint as well - see below).

In cellular biology, ribosomes are known to be bound to the endoplasmic reticulum's membrane, forming the rough endoplasmic reticulum, which is involved in protein synthesis. They can also be found on the outer membrane of the nuclear envelope, where they similarly engage in protein synthesis.

So yeah, there it goes, my 6 years younger self, hope it answered your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have no background in biology. Personally, I feel like the most likely interpretation is A.

If I had meant B, I would have written:

> ribosomes are *either* attached to the outside of the endoplasmic reticulum or *attached to the* nuclear envelope.